# Reduce space between subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

Do you know how to reduce the space between these plots?

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
axs[0].imshow(np.random.randint(0,15,size=(70,714)))
axs[1].imshow(np.random.randint(0,15,size=(70,714)))
plt.show()
```

I´m expected to generate the plots with only a small distance between them.

Comment: please format your code properly and include an image of the plots you are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fig.tight_layout` and adjust the height padding (`h_pad`) parameter as needed. For example:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2) 
fig.tight_layout(h_pad=-20)
axs[0].imshow(np.random.randint(0,15,size=(70,714))) 
axs[1].imshow(np.random.randint(0,15,size=(70,714))) 
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 1):

[Compressed layout](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/constrainedlayout_guide.html#grids-of-fixed-aspect-ratio-axes-compressed-layout) was designed for fixed aspect ratio plots such as this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, layout="compressed")
axs[0].imshow(np.random.randint(0,15,size=(70,714)))
axs[1].imshow(np.random.randint(0,15,size=(70,714)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this works without manual adjustment